# How to add thisType of List in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

How can I add this type of list, I need to add group and entry when to recuperate data from workflow is different TEST.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngx-treeview` package

```
npm install ngx-treeview --save
```

Detailed Link `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview`

Comment: for this tuto Angular treeview component with checkbox and i can't add group or entry . i need to Display this tree like picture